# Retrieving word document in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, web-services, ipad

I want to retrieve a word document through a web service call in Objective-C.

I have three question on this task:

1. How to retrieve the word document from a webservice call in Objective-C. (Inside the webservice I retrieve the document through a database call as the word document is stored in the database).
2. How can I store it in the sand box after retrieval ?
3. How to open the word document in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

1. Like any other binary file: eg pdf
2. Save it...[an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206013/save-and-load-data-iphone-sdk)
3. you can open as binary and it will be hard to display properly, but I am sure there are word viewer apps, and you can open with they.

Comment: To add to that last point, there's a tech note that lists the file formats that a UIWebView can display.  It includes newer versions of MSWord: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008749

Answer (score 0):

1. For retrieving a document I would use a networking library such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)
2. Then you can store it on you app Documents folder (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619719/write-a-file-on-ios) out)
3. The you can show your document using the Quicklook features of iOS. You may want to take a look at the [Document Interaction Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010409-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the QuickLook.framework. That can read all MS Office formats. Also can print from a supported AirPrint printer.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/

Example:- http://kratinmobile.com/blog/index.php/document-preview-in-ios-with-quick-look-framework/